# sql with rounding issue

Tags: sql, database, math, oracle10g

I have a problem with `sql`(maths).

I have a total payable given to vendor which is `33.333`, and I need to divide the amount with two users. So I have select

`select (16.666 * 2) from dual` which gives me `33.332` that is `.1` less than the total amount I have to give.

If I have this sql
`select (16.667 * 2) from dual`, then it gives me `33.334` which  `.1` greater than `33.333`.

How can I divide the total amount which I could equally distribute?

Thanks

Comment: What column types are you using in your tables and what database ? And just out of curiosity, what kind of currency are you using ? Normally cents aren't broken up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure from where are you executing your query, but it works here (SQLDeveloper, 10g):

```
SELECT (33.333 / 2) FROM dual;
16,6665

SELECT (16.6665 * 2) FROM dual;
33,333
```

Comment: I was multiplying with `select (16.666 * 2) from dual` which gives `33.332`. Is there any way with `3 decimal` points we could get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around:

```
select 33.333/2
```

Comment: When I divide, how can I divide it in this manner? `16.666` and `16.667`, summation of this becomes `33.333`

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely working with the wrong column type. You should be using DECIMAL instead of e.g. FLOAT.

Here is a good summary: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/189592

Depending on the SQL standard you are using the type can be MONEY, DECIMAL or NUMBER.

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g and datatype is number.

Comment: What's the exact definition ? Most likely you need to increase the precision and scale for the column type to fix this rounding error, e.g. number(8,4).See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209